# Add two variables to a Hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, links

I know this works:

```
= hyperlink( "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & B2 )
```

But I can't get two variables to work so the link would look like:

```
https://www.google.com?var1=[insert cell contents]&var2=[insert cell contents]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You say it doesn't work - what does it do when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= hyperlink( "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & B1 & "&var2=" & C1 )
```

This works for me.

Comment: Works for me too, thanks.  Not sure why someone down voted it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question

```
= hyperlink( "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & B2 & C2)
```

should suit. However, since the example you give is for a Google search and Google ignores punctuation in search terms (probably for the best!) ([see](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59879/google-displays-my-website-as-a-spelling-error) and tag wiki for [google-search]) there may be no need for two variables. Ie string terms together within B2 thus:

```
=C2&D2
```

So with that and  `paris` in C2 and `metro` in D2 took me to `https://www.google.com/search?q=parismetro`.

Comment: I just used Google as the URL as it came to mind for the example, this is not for a Google Search.  I need to have the var2= before the 2nd variable.